# Need help to make jQuery .find case insensitive

Tags: jquery

Trying to make this jQuery filter that uses .find case-insensitive.

For example, when the search = "cat" (no quotes) it will find "cat" but not "Cat" or "CAT". Similarly, "Cat" finds "Cat" but not "cat".

I suspect it's something very basic but cannot figure it out so I'm reaching out here with my first post.

I have no control over the contents of the list items themselves so cannot modify anything there,

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS Please no catcalls for something probably pretty junior for you guys. ;)

```
  $("#filter").live("keyup", function (ev) {
    var $filter = $(this),
        keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which,
        search;

    if (keyCode === 27) { //ESC
      $filter.val("");
    }

    search = $(this).val();
    $("#results").find("li").each(function () {
      var $li = $(this);
      if (search === "") {
        $li.show();
      } else {
        if (_.include(service_names, search)) {
          $li.toggle($li.hasClass("items-" + search));
        } else {
          if ($li.text().search(search) > 0) {
            $li.show();
          } else {
            $li.hide();
          }
        }
      }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to make case insensitive searches. try using regex `search(/string/i)`

```
$("#filter").live("keyup", function (ev) {
    var $filter = $(this),
        keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which,
        search;

    if (keyCode === 27) { //ESC
      $filter.val("");
    }

    search = $(this).val() ;
    // added
    var search_regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    $("#results").find("li").each(function () {
      var $li = $(this);
      if (search === "") {
        $li.show();
      } else {
        if (_.include(service_names, search)) {
          $li.toggle($li.hasClass("items-" + search));
        } else {
          // changed here
          if (search_regex.test($li.text())) {
            $li.show();
          } else {
            $li.hide();
          }
        }
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Yikes! That was fast. Quick check and it appears to work as hoped. Will test more in the morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Convert both strings to lowercase, and then do the search:

```
search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

$li.text().toLowerCase().search(search);
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried the first answer and it appears to work as hoped. Where would I put the second line you sent? What would make yours different?

Comment: I've just added `.toLowerCase()`, so you should be able to locate the line to fix. and what's the difference? type an invalid regexp (eg: `[`) in the search box and you'll see..

Comment: Yes, I applied your suggestion but cannot see any difference in results from the approach below. Both fixed the problem. Is there an advantage I'm missing to yours vs the other? Thanks!

Comment: I just told you the difference (please test it with both ones..) Regex isn't the right approach and an overkill anyway (but otherwise it's a good tool, I would suggest to learn what it does and then you'll understand how it can fail for this job)...  Also, there's a reason why only this answer has upvotes. sigh :)