# Highlight menu by querystring ignore case sensitive

Tags: jquery, html, menu, highlight, case-sensitive

I use jquery to highlight my menu. And here is my html look like

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="item"><a href="?product=abc">ABC</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="?product=XYZ">XYZ</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="?product=Test">Test</a></div>
</div>
```

assumed that i got value of current querystring: urlParams["product"] (by using Andy E's code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#menu").find("a[href='?product=" + urlParams["product"] + "']").addClass("selected");
    });
```

It only work if querystring exactly like a href. How can I make it non-case sensitive? Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009315/need-help-to-make-jquery-find-case-insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.toLowerCase()` method:

```
$("#menu").find("a").filter(function(){
    return this.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(urlParams["product"].toLowerCase()) > -1;
}).addClass("selected");
```

Or:

```
var query = urlParams["product"].toLowerCase();

$("#menu a").filter(function(){
   return this.href.split('=')[1].toLowerCase() === query;
}).addClass("selected");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RuYkn/